# Непонятки при Q_ENUMS и enums в разных классах

Tags: qt, qml

Приветствую! 
Например есть класс с перечислениями:

```
class ENUMS
{
public:
    ENUMS() {}
    enum enums1 {
        ENUM_1 = 123,
        ENUM_2 = 654,
        ENUM_3 = 455
    };
};
```

От него наследуется следующий класс:

```
class AppCore : public QObject, public ENUMS
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(enums1)

public:
    explicit AppCore(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void testEnum(enums1 e);

signals:

public slots:
};
```

Регистрирую его так:

```
 qmlRegisterType<AppCore>("app.appCore.dev", 1,0, "AppCore");
```

В QML пытаюсь вызвать функцию или использовать перечисления

```
import app.appCore.dev 1.0    
Window {
        visible: true
        property var appCore: null

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log(AppCore.ENUM_1);
                appCore.testEnum(AppCore.ENUM_1);
            }
        }

        Text {
            text: qsTr("Hello World")
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
```

получаю undefined и Error: Unknown method parameter type: enums1
как только переношу  enum enums1 { .... } в основной класс AppCore, то всё работает.  Почему так и как это обойти без изменения класса ENUMS?

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно, у вас `enum enum1` объявлен в базовом классе, поэтому из производного к нему надо обращаться, как к членам базового: `ENUMS::enum1`.